# How do I save a user's custom home page when they close my app in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, sharedpreferences

I am currently building an app that has a first page with two buttons: 'New users -->" and "Existing users -->". The goal is for new users to click their button and go through a setup process that ends with their unique home page that is saved when the app is closed. The next time a user opens the app, once they click their existing users button, I want the app to open to their unique home page. How do I achieve this? Please help!

Comment: Forgive me as I had do all this with archaic languages, but in other environments, would you not store that data into a database?  And then when the user logs in, it uses that data to pull the data pointing to their page data, pulls it and then displays it.   If that is the case here, does it suppose MySQL or what are you using to store the user data?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, I recommend that you save the values and then dynamically call and display them on the user page.

1. While the user is going through the setup process, save all the data in a database like [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive).
2. When u call the "existing user" page, simply read the stored user data and display it just the way you like it.
3. If you need more than one user. Create an object "User" with all the necessary parameters like "name, age, ...". Then save all the created users in the database and let the user choose which user should be displayed.